# How can it be defended that all Israel is Jewish?

Tags: judaism, israel

Many texts, publications, teachers, preachers etc. refer to ALL of Israel as Jewish.  I'm forgoing putting links herein as there are many references online quickly and easily found.  For example, "The 144,000 Jews of Revelation" as if all tribes are Jewish.  But, far more than that.  Some go as far as to say Abraham, Isaac and Jacob are Jewish.  And, teaching and prophetic interpretations abound with the assumption all of Israel is Jewish.

How can this be defended using scripture?

Scripture shows Abraham, Isaac and Jacob were Hebrew.  From Jacob, renamed Israel, on down all are "Israelites".  But, ONLY the tribe of Judah (mixed with Benjamin and some Levites) are "of Judah" aka Jewish.

It isn't a trivial distinction.  To properly identify who's being addressed to prophesies unto the end of this age, the understanding is quite different which side of this matter one views as who is Jewish with respect to Israel.

Comment: "The 144,000 Jews of Revelation" - If you are referring to Revelation 7:4-8, verse 4 says "Israel"; it does not use the term Jew(s).

Comment: @agarza, if you Google the term you'll have an endless list of references teaching/preaching/etc. to all the tribes as "Jews" although Rev 7:4 says "Israel".  That's the point of my question, how are so many conflating "Jews" with all 12 tribes and able to defend it using scriptural.

Comment: It's a [Synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche). Completely normal.

Comment: @curiousdannii, without scriptural support for that claim, 'completely normal' is wrong.  And, not insignificant as scripture is interpreted in a completely different manner than intended by the Lord.

Comment: Where's *your* evidence for what you think was intended by the Lord?

Comment: Briefly, House of Israel and House of Judah addressed unto the end of the age; the very world "Jewish" or "Jew" is "Of Judah".  Other tribes are not "Of Judah", biblical lineage proves Abraham, Isaac and Jacob aren't Jews, they're Hebrews.  & a ton of scripture making explicit who's being addressed this space wouldn't permit.

Comment: If you're already including Benjamin and Levi in the "Jews", then you're already using the term as a synecdoche. Yes it's anachronistic to refer to the patriarchs as "Jews", but that's really not very common. Some members of the other tribes returned to the land after the exile, and so they too are included in the "Jews". (There's no such thing as the 10 lost tribes. See for example Anna in Luke 2:36.)

Comment: @curiousdannii, I'm not referring to the 10 lost tribes.  Benjamin resided in Judah and the Levites had orders whereby some would be in Jerusalem during their time of service.  Thus, some were included in the southern kingdom, the House of Judah.  The very word "Jew" or "Jewish" refers to "of Judah".

Comment: @Ben Exactly - a synecdoche. And some people from the other tribes were also there too. So what's the issue?

Comment: @curiousdannii, "So what's the big issue?" is stated in the question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The ten tribes were lost after the Assyrian Captivity. Those who came back from the second captivity (the Babylonian Captivity) to re-build the temple in Jerusalem were of Judah.

They were Jewish.

Yes, Abraham was an Hebrew. But from the time of the second captivity, only Judah (Jews) were left in whom prophecy could be fulfilled.

Thence came Christ who is come, in respect of the flesh, of the tribe of Judah. That all prophecies might be fulfilled in Him.

Comment: Some members of the other tribes returned to the land after the exile. There's no such thing as truly lost tribes. See for example Anna in Luke 2:36.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, indeed, but generally it was so and it was so in the judgment of God. And the term 'Jew' reflects that judgment.